# Kill, abort, stop, cancel a previous call/queue to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, abort

I have a function which will take some time to run on  `click` event.
Following is merely an example and `setTimeout` is there only to **simulate** time it may take to run it. How can I ensure when a user click on an item any previous running function(s) is(are) cancelled and only the latest `onclick` function is fired?

i.e. if a user clicked on it 10 times. I want to only execute the only the 10th click not the 9 clicks before.

I am hoping for a pure/vanilla js solution... NOT jQuery

```
(function () {

    var nav = document.querySelector('.nav__toggle');
    var toggleState = function (elem, one, two) {
        var elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        elem.setAttribute('data-state', elem.getAttribute('data-state') === one ? two : one);
    };

    nav.onclick = function (e) {
        setTimeout(function(){
        toggleState('.nav ul', 'closed', 'open');
        }, 5000);
        e.preventDefault();
    };

})();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6p94p48m/

Comment: Well, what's your actual function? How can it be cancelled? For `setTimeout` a `clearTimeout` is quite trivial

Comment: This absolutely screams [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Try to explain what you're actually trying to do, not some vague notion of it.

Comment: it's too long/modular... my actual function have several setters + getters and animations(add/remove classes). Everytime the `target` get clicked `click`/`keyup` event runs again. This creates bit of lag. I would like to prevent that happening.

Comment: Setters and getters should neither be async nor have any side effects. About those animations, can you stop them? How?

Comment: I am not sure...  classes get added and removed and they seems to fire one after the other... I just want the latest one... that's what I am trying to find out... I think `debounce` seems to kind of thing I am looking for I am going to try one of them...

Comment: You cannot cancel a trivial function, because if it is called it will continue execution till the end(and then js-engine will pass control to the caller function). But you can use the special function, which is wrapped over your main function. Ant this wrapper will run your target function only _debounce time_  later. And if you call this function again during _debounce time_ again, previous call will be cancelled.

Answer (score 1):

You need to debounce your click handler.

```js
var button = document.getElementById("debounced");
var clickHandler = function() {
  alert('click handler');
}

var debounce = function(f, debounceTimeout) {
  var to;

  return function() {
    clearTimeout(to);
    to = setTimeout(f, debounceTimeout);
  }
}

button.addEventListener('click', debounce(clickHandler, 5000));
```

```html
<button id="debounced" href="#">debounced</button>
```

Or use underscore/lodash https://lodash.com/docs#debounce